# Root project version is not set for subprojects

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm packaging multi-project sbt build with `sbt package` and have the following version property set in the `build.sbt` root:

```
version := "1.0.0"
```

But unfortunately the aggregated subprojects `jar` are all have `0.1.0-SNAPSHOT` suffix unless I specify a `version :=` for each of the subproject specifically. Is there a way to propagate the `version := "1.0.0"` set in the `build.sbt` root? Or any other way to set a version for all the aggregated subprojects?

I tried

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(
       //...
   )
  .settings(
    version := "1.0.0",
    //...
   )
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Use `ThisBuild / version := "1.0.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Examples of scoped key notation in the sbt shell](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scopes.html#Examples+of+scoped+key+notation+in+the+sbt+shell):

> - `ThisBuild / version` sets the subproject axis to “entire build” where the build is ThisBuild, with the default configuration.

Therefore, as @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez mentioned in the comment, the following should do that:

```
ThisBuild / version := "1.0.0"
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(
       //...
   )
  .settings(
    //...
   )
```

In general, I'd recommend reading about [Scopes](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scopes.html#Scopes) in sbt.